# how to execute multiple conditions with try/catch in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to execute a code that should give the output after verifying if any of the 6 conditions I define.
Is there any other way I can achieve that with try/catch method. Any other method is also appreciated.
This is the code I came up with so far:-

```
 try { 
         if(drv.findElement(By.id("errorExplanation"))!= null){

          System.out.println("Email already present");  
                }
         }

         catch (Exception e) {
          if(drv.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='new_spree_user']/div[2]/div[4]/span"))!= null){

                  System.out.println("Issue in Email");  
              }
         }

         try {
             if(drv.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='password-credentials']/span"))!=null){
                 System.out.println("Issue in Password");
             }
         }

         catch (Exception e) {
            if(drv.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='errorExplanation']/ul/li[2]"))!= null){
                System.out.println("Empty Password");
            }
            }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use the plural version findElements(), it returns a list. If no element found then size will be 0. Check size...

Answer (score 0):

`driver.findElement()` will not return `null` if no element is found so your condition that checks that is not necessary. If no element is found, an exception is thrown which you are catching. You can avoid all the `try/catch`es by using `.findElements()` (note the plural). If the element is not found, an empty list will be returned. You can then check for an empty list and avoid all the exceptions.

For example, here are the first couple... I'll let you do the rest.

```
if (!driver.findElements(By.id("errorExplanation")).isEmpty())
{
    System.out.println("Email already present");
}
if (!driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='new_spree_user']/div[2]/div[4]/span")).isEmpty())
{
    System.out.println("Issue in Email");
}
```